# "Whale fail" - What does this mean?

Tags: meaning

Google uses the phrase "Whale fail" on this picture (from their [error page](http://books.google.com/googlebooks/error.html)):

[image: Google Books "whale fail" image, Captain Ahab dejected at finding a green whale]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a reference to the Twitter "[fail whale](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/the_story_of_the_fail_whale.php)", integrating a Google-Books-appropriate collateral reference to [*Moby Dick*](http://books.google.com/books?id=XV8XAAAAYAAJ).  (It appears that Captain Ahab is dejected because the whale in front of him is green, not white; his search for the white whale has suffered a case of "whale fail".)  This is all related to the fairly recent, Internet-driven [nouning of the verb "fail"](http://arnoldzwicky.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/no-nouning/).

It doesn't actually *mean* anything other than that your Web request failed.

Comment: "I wonder if it'll be friendly."

Answer (score 0):

The term "whale fail" or "fail whale" is in common usage to denote a failure of substantially vast proportion. See the **[Urban Dictionary entry for whale fail](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whale%20fail)**.

Similar phrases are "Epic fail", "Failtastic" and "All aboard the fail boat".

A known variant of the fail whale, the "red fail whale" also appears as an indication of a network connection failure in the popular Twitter client *DestroyTwitter*.